# Kubernetes 1.2alpha8 AWS Container Registry Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

Was trying to integrate kubernetes with AWS Container Registry. From what I have read it sounds like it should be automatically setup if the cluster is deployed to AWS. Which my cluster is.

I also granted the IAM Roles the necessary permissions to pull from ecr but I still get unable to pull image when trying to deploy on kubernetes. It also says authentication failed.

Really just wanted to see if anyone else was having issues or if someone was able to pull an image from aws ecr and how did they accomplish it.

Comment: Are you able to pull images directly on the nodes?

Comment: This issue was just opened yesterday. I was trying the exact same setup. Cluster in West region while ecr is in East region.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/21783